# Pygame Rect. Проверка: в диапазоне объекта находится другой объект.

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Здравствуйте!
Мне нужно сделать проверку на нахождение одного объекта в диапазоне 'top' и 'bottom' другого (Смотрите Картинку). 
То есть, если один объект находится "одном уровне" со вторым выполнять какое-то действие, допустим, `print('Hello World!')`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала давайте дадим имя нашим объектам. Первый назовем `object1`, а второй - `object2`. Добавим некие картинки:

```
image_obj1 = pg.image.load('images/obj1.png')
image_obj2 = pg.image.load('images/obj2.png')
```

Теперь требуется получить их координаты функцией `get_rect()`:

```
object1.rect = image_obj1.get_rect()
object2.rect = image_obj2.get_rect()
```

Для того, чтобы выполнить то, что мне требовалось достаточно сделать такую проверку:

```
if object1.rect.top <= object2.rect.top  <= object1.rect.bottom:
    print('Hello World!')
```

Так, как `object2` является меньшим, чем `object1`, мы проверяем, находится ли он между координатами `top` и `bottom` большего объекта - `object1`.